# XDocument Decendants with Namespaces

Tags: c#, xml, linq, linq-to-xml

I have this xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<CueList xmlns="urn:CueListSchema.xml" xmlns:s="urn:schemas-rcsworks-com:SongSchema" xmlns:n="urn:schemas-rcsworks-com:NoteSchema" xmlns:l="urn:schemas-rcsworks-com:LinkSchema" xmlns:t="urn:schemas-rcsworks-com:TrafficSchema" xmlns:p="urn:schemas-rcsworks-com:ProductSchema" xmlns:m="urn:schemas-rcsworks-com:MediaSchema" xmlns:w="urn:schemas-rcsworks-com:WebPageSchema" xmlns:ns="urn:CueListSchema.xml" time="2011-12-02T13:34:39">
   <Event eventID="14" eventType="song" status="happening" scheduledTime="13:34:38" scheduledDuration="332.82">
      <s:Song title="Long Time Coming (Holding On)" internalID="007700028007AD480000">
         <s:Artist name="The Winans" sequenceNumber="1" internalID="0067000180002B020000" sortName="Winans, The" />
         <m:Media ID="{7C734B6C-7AF7-4998-8366-F1F11F5D56D7}" runTime="332.82" fileName="{7C734B6C-7AF7-4998-8366-F1F11F5D56D7}.wav" />
      </s:Song>
   </Event>
   <Event eventID="15" eventType="link" status="committed" startTime="13:40:10" scheduledDuration="3.49">
      <l:Link title="PG MFL DRY FEMALE" internalID="007B00028002DAEA0000">
         <m:Media ID="{036BB0ED-3130-4AD0-8BAF-E5D0FBA7DC3B}" runTime="3.49" fileName="{036BB0ED-3130-4AD0-8BAF-E5D0FBA7DC3B}.wav" />
      </l:Link>
   </Event>
   <Event eventID="16" eventType="song" status="committed" startTime="13:40:10" scheduledDuration="303.55">
      <s:Song title="Not Making Sense, Making Faith" internalID="007700028009377F0000">
         <s:Artist name="Donald Lawrence" sequenceNumber="1" internalID="006700018000308A0000" sortName="Lawrence, Donald" />
         <m:Media ID="{B6FD04EA-9B42-4E6A-AC80-A26BF65E6F11}" runTime="303.55" fileName="{B6FD04EA-9B42-4E6A-AC80-A26BF65E6F11}.wav" />
      </s:Song>
   </Event>
</CueList>
```

I am able to set the namespaces for songs etc. But when I try and select Events it does not work, I tried setting the namespace for CueList and when I debug it says that namespace is null?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's hard to know what's wrong when you haven't shown the code you're using, but it should be simple:

```
XNamespace ns = "urn:CueListSchema.xml";
var events = doc.Descendants(ns + "Event");
```

If that doesn't work, please give us a *short* but complete example of both the XML (formatted, please, and not just copied from a browser) and code you're using.